# Colors for Python (seaborn): colors without adding to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, colors, seaborn

```
slov = {'People': {0: 'Ivan', 1: 'John', 2: 'Peter', 3: 'Ming'}, 'Country':{0: 'Russia', 1: 'USA', 2: 'USA', 3: 'China'},\
    'Height': {0: 181, 1: 175, 2: 174, 3: 173}}
```

I'd like to see this picture

[image: Colors for different countries]

But I don't know how to do it. I mean I want to have a red color for Russian people, Green color for USA people and yellow color for Chines.

**My attemp to find solution:**

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
sns.set(style="white")

slov = {'People': {0: 'Ivan', 1: 'John', 2: 'Peter', 3: 'Ming'}, 'Country':{0: 'Russia', 1: 'USA', 2: 'USA', 3: 'China'},\
'Height': {0: 181, 1: 175, 2: 174, 3: 173}}

obj = pd.DataFrame(slov)

palette=["g", "b", "r"]
obj['Color']='r'

row_index = obj.Country == 'Russia'
obj.loc[row_index, 'Color'] = 'r'

row_index = obj.Country == 'USA'
obj.loc[row_index, 'Color'] = 'g'

row_index = obj.Country == 'China'
obj.loc[row_index, 'Color'] = 'y'


g = sns.factorplot(x="People", y="Height",  data=obj, kind='bar', palette=obj['Color'])

plt.show()
```

And maybe my solution is not very good. I added color to DataFrame. Maybe we can write this better. Maybe I don't need to add color to my DataFrame (It seems not very correct.). But How can I solve my task without adding these colors to my DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
d = {'Russia':'r', 'USA':'g','China':'y'}
g = sns.factorplot(x="People", 
                   y="Height",  
                   data=obj, 
                   kind='bar', 
                   palette=obj['Country'].map(d))

plt.show()
```

[image: graph]